# When booting my bios pops up i think? And it sais this a bunch of times

Tags: boot, grub2

```
[  158.926996] usb 2-6: Device not responding to set address.
[  159.131119] usb 2-6: Device not responding to set address.
```

But I'm not booting off a usb device. Originally when I downloaded Ubuntu I believe that I had. Its been doing this ever since I installed Ubuntu onto my laptop as the main system. I only use Ubuntu. I don't believe it's affecting anything but it just annoys me that it says error cant find address. I'm not sure what I need to post in order to solve this issue. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

USB has over-current protection, which gets triggered when power consumption from the port is too high.

Unplug all USB devices from PC, turn power off, and wait a minute or two. Plug everything back and boot into Linux.

I cant take credit for this. I found it at https://paulphilippov.com/articles/how-to-fix-device-not-accepting-address-error